# Using italic instead of bold in newenvironment

Tags: environments

The following is printing `Proof:` in bold.  How can avoid the bold typeface, and use italic instead?

```
   \newenvironment{galexproof}
     {
       \paragraph{\textit{Proof:}}
     }
     {\hfill \textdagger}
```

Comment: By default, `\paragraph` makes its argument bold.  Is there a reason you want the paragraph command?  The only reason I can think of is if you have the numbering that far down.

Comment: Fastest way to change it is probably something like `\usepackage{titlesec}\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\itshape}`, but there may be even shorter ways depending on document class. (BTW you've been asking a *lot* of questions over the past couple days; you might consider reading some LaTeX books and documentation so you can answer your own questions.)

Comment: I can do without the paragraph command.

Comment: You're probably better of copying the proof code from amsthm. That enddagger will not be at the right edge in all cases with this construction